# Different between navigation.goBack() and navigation.dispatch(CommonActions.goBack())

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm new to react native. The following two functions allow us to return to the previous page. So is there any difference between them?

() => navigation.dispatch(CommonActions.goBack())

() => navigation.goBack()